# MySQL query claims point is not within polygon

Tags: mysql, geolocation, geospatial

I've drawn a polygon which contains a point in Google Maps. But if I pass the coordinates to MySQL to calculate if the point is within the polygon, it returns false.

```sql
SELECT ST_Within(
    ST_GeomFromText('POINT(8.34047 54.91320)', 4326),
    ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((62.144619879597 10.486242310988,54.622536815923 2.3124141859883,55.403637023919 23.977453248488,62.144619879597 10.486242310988))', 4326)
) AS is_point_within_polygon;
```

=> returns `0`

But the point is obviously within the polygon:

[image]

I double-checked that using Python:

```py
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon

if __name__ == '__main__':
    v0 = [62.144619879597, 10.486242310988]
    v1 = [54.622536815923, 2.3124141859883]
    v2 = [55.403637023919, 23.977453248488]
    lats_vect = np.array([v0[0], v1[0], v2[0]])
    lons_vect = np.array([v0[1], v1[1], v2[1]])

    lats_vect = np.append(lats_vect, lats_vect[0])
    lons_vect = np.append(lons_vect, lons_vect[0])

    lons_lats_vect = np.column_stack((lons_vect, lats_vect))
    polygon = Polygon(lons_lats_vect)
    point = Point(8.34047, 54.9132)
    print(point.within(polygon))
```

=> prints `True`

What's wrong with the MySQL query?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two issues here:

1. First with the query. You list polygon in lat-lon order, but the point seems to be in lon-lat order. You probably want

```
SELECT ST_Within(
    ST_GeomFromText('POINT(54.91320 8.34047)', 4326),  -- NOTE CHANGE HERE
    ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((62.144619879597 10.486242310988,54.622536815923 2.3124141859883,55.403637023919 23.977453248488,62.144619879597 10.486242310988))', 4326)
) AS is_point_within_polygon;
```

2. Even this query returns FALSE, and this is expected in MySQL. 4326 is Geodesic coordinate system, meaning it operates on the spherical Earth, not on this flat map. With geodesic CRS, edges follow the geodesic shortest lines on Earth, not straight lines on flat map, and for really long lines like here and points close to the edge it matter:

[image]

Points slightly further North would be within the polygon, e.g. check out

```
SELECT ST_Within(
    ST_GeomFromText('POINT(56 8.34047)', 4326),
    ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((62.144619879597 10.486242310988,54.622536815923 2.3124141859883,55.403637023919 23.977453248488,62.144619879597 10.486242310988))', 4326)
) AS is_point_within_polygon
```

Comment: I actually use `ST_SRID(POINT(a, b), c)` instead of `ST_GeomFromText('POINT(a b)', c)`. But I just noticed that the order of lat/lon is dependent of the EPSG you pass to the functions. Both `SELECT ST_SRID(POINT(8.34047, 54.91320), 4326) = ST_GeomFromText('POINT(54.91320 8.34047)', 4326)` and `SELECT ST_SRID(POINT(54.91320, 8.34047), 3857) = ST_GeomFromText('POINT(54.91320 8.34047)', 3857)` return `1`! I don't know what's going on here. But the solution to my problem was to use 3857, which is used by Google Maps, and to adjust the lat/lon order accordingly. Thank you!

Comment: Calling ST_SRID is same as passing it directly. Re what's going on here, see second part of my answer about geodesic edges used by 4326.